# When should one use time series analysis vs. non-time series analysis?

Tags: python, machine-learning, churn

I am trying to predict churn and for this my dependent variable is a binary variable. The independent variables can be categorical, integer or timeseries data. I am in the feature selection mode and will like to know if I am running correlation, should I run correlation on time series data or not. If I do use a wrapper method and use a ML algorithm for such a problem, do I use models like ARIMA that are more suited for time series analysis or a decision tree model?

I have tried using Spearman correlation but am not finding any significant correlated dependent variables

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mixed up your dependent and independent variables. I assume when you say "my independent variable is a binary variable" that this is referring to your active/inactive membership (or whatever is appropriate for your service), correct? If so, this should be the dependent variable. You may have misstated it, I may misunderstand, or this may be the course of your problem. Let me know and then I'll follow up. 

Also, welcome!

Comment: Todd, you are absolutely right and I did mix those up. I will update the question. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: Sounds good. With that out of the way, have you considered more basic approaches first, such as logistic regression or survival analysis? You mentioned Spearman's not being helpful, but that doesn't necessarily preclude a logit model with multiple independent variables.

Comment: Hi Todd, No I have not tried out a logit model, will do that tonight and circle back with my observations.

Comment: Cool. If you want to post sample code myself (or others) could run things as well. I guess you're using Python, which is good for ML, but if you're familiar with R it can be easier/quicker when doing a more basic Statistical analysis. Don't know how much of this you're going to be doing, but that's something to consider.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: We are discussing high level coding concepts. Please dont close this question

Comment: Todd, I was able to run a logistic regression and given p values were below 0.05 for select variables I am interpreting it as having them being significant in explaining the change in the dependent variable. However, why is it that the Spearman correlation does not show significance and logistic regression does?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely should! Since churn rate may be affected by macroeconomical issues that will show in your autocorrelation function. I suggest paying a visit to statsmodel and making sure you understand ACF plots and PACF plots (that can be done with statsmodel quite easily) together with ARIMA models so you can do some fine tuning. As for the feature selection, you can try using an overfitted neural network or model with L1 regularization. 
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html

Comment: Celius, so in this case my dependent variable would be 1 for all active periods vs 0 for the churned period and then independent variable values for all the periods. Is this correct?